# Parse only 2 defined columns html table into dictionary for later usage

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

i am trying to `parse` only 2 columns of a html tabled that I got from a website with the `requests` module. What I could do is to sort all the columns into a row in a file so that is easily to be read but I actually need that in a `dictionary` so I can later compare the `Clan Days` for the username `SirFulgeruL` for example with a `integer`
Here is my code so far:

```
from html_table_extractor.extractor import Extractor

table_doc = """
<table class="table table-bordered">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th><i class="fa fa-sort-numeric-desc"></i> Rank</th>
<th><i class="fa fa-address-card"></i> Name</th>
<th><i class="fa fa-usd"></i> Deposited money</th>
<th><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Clan Days</th>
<th>Time last 7 days</th>
<th><i class="fa fa-gear"></i> Options</th> </tr>
<tr>
<td>7</td>
<td><i class="fa fa-circle text-red" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="offline"></i> <a href="https://jadepanel.nephrite.ro/profile/SirFulgeruL2k19">SirFulgeruL2k19</a></td>
<td><font style="color:green">$417,090</font></td>
<td>140</td>
<td>11:57</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>6</td>
<td><i class="fa fa-circle text-red" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="offline"></i> <a href="https://jadepanel.nephrite.ro/profile/Darius">Darius</a></td>
<td><font style="color:green">$2,717,020</font></td>
<td>127</td>
<td>09:42</td>
<td><a onclick="remove_clan(3080)">uninvite</a></td>
</tr>
""""

extractor = Extractor(table_doc).parse()
extractor.write_to_csv(path='.')
```

Later edit:

After some time I could parse only the days from the table only, for some reasons I can't parse the names.

```
from lxml import etree
parser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree = etree.fromstring(table_doc, parser)
days = tree.xpath('//tr/td[position()=4]')

print ('Column 2\n========')
for r in days:
    print (r.text)
```

Comment: For some reasons it doesn't add after `data-original-title="offline"></i>` the username `<a href="https://jadepanel.nephrite.ro/profile/Darius">Darius</a></td>`
so it looks like this : `<td><i class="fa fa-circle text-red" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="offline"></i> <a href="https://jadepanel.nephrite.ro/profile/Darius">Darius</a></td>`

Comment: From the code I see that you are trying to save only 2 columns (with relative) header to a .csv, it is correct? We can't tell why it isn't working if there isn't the code of the extractor doing the work. Add this information to have a correct and precise answer.

Comment: @Iulian `extractor = Extractor(table_doc).parse()
extractor.write_to_csv(path='.') `this is the code that prases the columns in a .csv file and it looks like this: ` Rank, Name, Deposited money, Clan Days,Time last 7 days, Options

7, SirFulgeruL2k19,"$417,090",140,11:57,` but I only want to save the `Name` and the `Clan days` into dictionary .

Comment: @Iulian: I assume that OP is using a package from [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/html-table-extractor/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, you are able to use html_table_extractor to extract tabular data from html into a csv file named `output.csv`.

The next operation is to parse that file with the standard library `csv` module:

```
...
import csv
with open('output.csv') as fd:
    rd = csv.DictReader(fd, skipinitialspace=True)
    for row in rd:
        print({ k: row[k] for k in row if k in ['Name', 'Clan Days']})
```

This will output:

```
{'Name': 'SirFulgeruL2k19', 'Clan Days': '140'}
{'Name': 'Darius', 'Clan Days': '127'}
```

Comment: thank you so much. I have 1 more questions sadly.. I can't figure it out how I can compare the `Clan Days` only from 1 username with another variable for example. I tried everything I could think of and also searched on google but didn't found anything.